# How to fix 'Column Reference X is ambiguous' error in postgresql..?

Tags: postgresql-9.6

I'm trying to join some tables in my database, but I found error..

I using Postgresql-9.6

```
SELECT
    customer_id
  , (select identity_card_number from basic_customer bc where bc.customer_id = ba.customer_id ) as identitu_card_number
  , (select fullname from customer_pedal cp where cp.customer_id = ba.customer_id ) as fullname
  , customer_id
  , category_code
  , (select is_cif_active_desc from basic_customer bc where bc.customer_id = ba.customer_id ) as is_active
  , ba.account_number
  , opening_date
  , closure_date
  , currency_code
  , (SELECT balance_date FROM basic_balance bb where bb.account_number = ba.account_number )  as balance_date
  , (SELECT balance_amount FROM basic_balance bb where bb.account_number = ba.account_number )  as balance_amount
  , (select description from customer_pedal cp where cp.customer_id = ba.customer_id ) as description
FROM basic_account ba
INNER JOIN customer_pedal cp on cp.customer_id = ba.customer_id
WHERE ba.customer_id is not  null;
```

I expected data where contain only customer id from basic_account and customer_pedal.

Here is the structure tables
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show the structure tables and the error detail?

Comment: Prefix **all** column references with their table names or aliases  at least one of the non-prefixed columns exists in  more than one table (e.g. `select cp.customer_id, ...`

Comment: I did add prefix all column references with their table aliases and it works, thank you @a_horse_with_no_name , you save my day..